# Android - set text size programatically cuts off words

Tags: android, textview

So I am using a library for resizing the text to fit within bounds: https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview. What I am trying to do is to loop through an ArrayList of text view and find the lowest text size and then set that text size to every text view.
My Java Code:

```
//Loop through every textview and get lowest size
        float lowestTextSize = textViews.get(0).getTextSize();
        for (TextView textView : textViews){
            if(lowestTextSize > textView.getTextSize()){
                lowestTextSize = textView.getTextSize();
            }
        }

        lowestTextSize = lowestTextSize / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;

        //Loop through every textview and set them all to the lowest text size previously found
        for (TextView textView : textViews){
            textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, lowestTextSize);
        }
```

My problem is that after setting that size to every textview the size of the textview changes but not the size of the words itself, so I get words cut in half (**exception making the word whos size I am using, the one resized by the AutoFit library**):
[image]

Any idea on how to solve this?

My XML code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/highestSellingProductLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
            android:id="@+id/highestSellingProduct"
            autofit:minTextSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:text="NA"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSuccess"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
            autofit:minTextSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:text="Highest Selling"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Increase layout height

Comment: it is of no use. because my purpose is to resize the text according to the lowest size text...as you can see the text is not resized its cut off....it stays the same size

Comment: getTextSize() returns the actual pixel dimensions of the text. Try TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX

Comment: may be you have fixed the height of your textview, try using wrap_content instead of hard coded height, Or might be the problem with padding of your textview

Comment: @ĜüptåŠhãsĥwæt the height of the textview is not fixed

Comment: @PrisonMike as you can see here: lowestTextSize = lowestTextSize / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;    I am converting the pixels to sp

Comment: oh sorry overlooked that

Comment: I guess you are having a padding around the text view which is also based on the size of text....

Comment: @ProgrammingPirate I added a sample of my xml

Comment: I tried it myself in Android Studio, this code should work perfectly

Comment: The weight of the linear layout is causing the issue.

Comment: The code is identical for the LeastSelling as well...and that one scales correctly

Comment: Programming Pirate is right. Nested weights are always bad

Comment: I have given up the weight in favour of wrap_content but I have the same result.

Comment: Check this answer and stop using that lib: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5535672/3465623

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue. To change the size of text in java using AutofitTextView I had to use autofitHelper on every textview. The following code worked for me:

```
 //Loop through every textview and get lowest size
    float lowestTextSize = textViews.get(0).getTextSize();
    for (TextView textView : textViews){
        if(lowestTextSize > textView.getTextSize()){
            lowestTextSize = textView.getTextSize();
        }
    }

    lowestTextSize = lowestTextSize / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;

    //Loop through every textview and set them all to the lowest text size previously found
    for (TextView textView : textViews){
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, lowestTextSize);
        AutofitHelper autofitHelper = AutofitHelper.create(textView);
        autofitHelper.setTextSize(textView.getTextSize());
    }
```